Is $\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E} [ T \mid T\ge t, L] ] = \mathbb{E} [ T ]$ correct?
Given $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are sigma algebra. I have learned in my probability class that if $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$, then the following result, so called tower property holds:
$$\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[ X\mid \mathcal{F} ]\mid \mathcal{G}  ] = \mathbb{E}[ X\mid \mathcal{G} ].$$
I want to use this result in a special problem. Let's say I have a random variable $T$ whose sample space is $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, $L$ is any arbitrary random variable, $t$ is a fixed positive number.
Since $\emptyset\subset \sigma(\textbf{1}(T\ge t), L)$, using the above reasult, can I get
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[ T \mid T\ge t, L ]] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[ T \mid T\ge t, L ]\mid \emptyset] = \mathbb{E}[ T \mid \emptyset] = \mathbb{E}[ T]?
\end{equation}
I understand $\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[ T \mid L ]] =  \mathbb{E}[ T]$ for sure, I think the complication arises from the conditioning on the event $\{T\ge t\}$, or the indicator random variable $\textbf{1}(T\ge t)$.
Since $[t,\infty)\subset \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, so what I did is first split the sample space $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ into two subsample spaces $[0,t)$ and $[t,\infty)$, and conditioning on one of the subsample space $[t,\infty)$ and an arbitrary r.v. $L$.
If $\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[ T \mid T\ge t, L ]]\ne \mathbb{E}[ T]$, may I ask where in my thought process goes wrong?

The empty set is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

But your claim is anyways correct by the "Total Law of Expectation".

Got it, thank you so much for pointing it out!

You're welcome :)

The statement $E[E[X\lvert \mathcal{G}] ] = EX$ is always true for any random variable $X$ and any sub $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$. As noted in the comments, this is the law of total expectation. As for your approach, I guess that what you wanted to do is define $\mathcal{A} = \{ \emptyset, \mathcal{X}\}$ ($\mathcal{X}$ being the whole space) which is the coarse $\sigma$-algebra. But you are applying the tower property incorrectly. Notice that $\sigma(\mathbb{1}_{T\geq t}, L)$ corresponds with your $\mathcal{F}$ in the tower property, and not with $\mathcal{G}$. That being said since $E[T \lvert T \geq t, L]$ is, like every random variable, independent of $\mathcal{A}$ you can proceed to write
$$E[E[T \lvert T \geq t, L]] = E[E[T \lvert T \geq t, L]\lvert \mathcal{A}]  = E[T].$$
and you would be correct. But this would not in general hold for $\mathcal{G} \subset \sigma(\mathbb{1}_{T\geq t}, L)$.
